# How to connect to VPN through firewall

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vpn, firewall, pptp

Our admins had blocked all outgoing ports except few like 80, 443, 110 etc. I want to use some software that utilizes other ports. So I decided to make a VPN connection to my dedicated server.

So we have:

- Server, that has Ubuntu 10.04, external ip and I have root access to this box
- Client, windows 7, NAT, and paranoid external firewall that blocks almost everything

How to setup VPN in this environment and configure it to use different ports like 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) and configure the port you want to use it in config file.

### On the client side, you use:

```
remote server_address_or_IP PORT
```

To change the port you connect on server.

If you want to change the port used by the client (local port) (not very usual but seems to be what you need), you can use:

```
lport PORT
```

directive and don't use `nobind`

Comment: how to configure ports at client side?

Comment: openvpn config file has a line to input the port. answer updated

Comment: client is windows 7. is openvpn available for both systems?

Comment: yes - I never used it on win7 but it is available according to site. I use it on XP and linux.