# Is there a way to run VPN behind a heavy handed uni firewall?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, proxy, firewall

I would like to run a VPN or similar solutions to change my IP while surfing the web from my work PC. I am connected to internet via Ethernet, and through my university network, which is heavily protected with firewall. I have admin control over my pc but no access or control over the router.

I tried different VPNs (i.e. tor, vanilla, CyberGhost, ProXPN, and VyperVPN) and none of them can connect to internet.

next, I tried to check which ports are open. I used sites like http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/  to find open ports, but they say all common ports are closed, even port 80 and 443 ?! How is it possible? I can browse internet with no problem even https sites load correctly.

The IP used by the port scan websites, is the one detected by the websites and is different from the one I see in the ipconfig command.

Why the port scanner cannot find any open port, even port 443 and 80?

Is it possible to run a VPN under these conditions? even if it is a paid service.

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/379840/how-to-connect-to-vpn-through-firewall?rq=1) talks about how you do that in a general sense.

Comment: You need an external VPN service (whether your own or purchased) that runs on true SSL over port TCP 443. Then you install the client on your local workstation, tell the client software to connect via the IP of the VPN server, and voila. SoftEther is one that I've used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you are under a very restrictive firewall . Yet there is a way around it. But first the answer to your question.

Such sites detect whether ports are open, in the sense that they are ready to accept connections initiated outside their perimeter, *i.e.* outside your University. The ports were all found to be closed (filtered would have been better, but never mind), which means at your IP address there is no server of any kind waiting for connections to come in. However, as you correctly pointed out, you **can** initiate http/https connections to the outside world. They go through your firewall because legitimate users (*i.e.*, those within the school IP perimeter) can start connections and surf the Web.

In other words, your firewall blocks all *incoming* connections, while it allows *outgoing* connections, at least on ports 80 and 443.

As for your question:

> Is there a way to run VPN behind a heavy handed uni firewall?

Do you mean a server or a client?

**A server**: No. We just saw your firewall blocks all incoming connections, hence a server would never be reached by anyone.

**A client**: yes, if you use an outside OpenVPN server (whether for pay, or on a machine you control) which listens on port TCP443. Many commercial servers are ready to offer you service on this port, **exactly** because many users are behind very restrictive firewalls. If instead you rent a cheap VPS with a good provider and setup your own instance of OpenVPN, then you control the listening **port** and **protocol**, hence you can elect to listen on TCP443.

Please be careful, the  reference pointed to by Ramhound makes no mention of the protocol. By default, OpenVPN uses UDP, not TCP; but your firewall most likely will block UDP443 because it seems to have been erected by competent, if overcautious, people. You will need to change the protocol to TCP as well.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your complete answer. I meant using VPN as a client. I wonder why still I cannot use VyperVPN installed on my PC on port 443?! It says it cannot access the server. Is it possible for the network admin to somehow detect and filter such VPN usage, e.g by packet sniffing, etc ?

Comment: @cybergeek654 Are you using encryption? If you are not, then it can. If you are, and still cannot contact, then someone has done a very good job by logging the IPs of VyperVPN, and blocking all traffic to those. That's why I suggested using a cheap VPS. Mine costs 3.95 dollars per month, you can try with little expenditure, and see whether it works.

Comment: @cybergeek654 An afterthought: are you trying to contact VypervPN via name or you have the numerical address? If the latter, I can sole your problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I contacted VyprVPN and they even gave me ip address of one of their servers to try. I still could not connect to their server. Regarding the VPS, it is a good idea, but I also wanted to benefit from surfing web with random IPs, and hence anonymous. By using a VPS, my IP will always be the IP of the server and a fixed one, right?

Comment: @cybergeek654 Yes it will.